# Characteristic Primes of repunits

Tags: number-theory

First off, we're working in base 10. A repunit is a number of form   $111111...1$.  ( n ones)

For some integer sequence $(a_n)$, a charateristic prime $p$ of $a_n$ is a prime which divides $a_n$, but none of $a_1,...,a_n$. Does every repunit have a charteristic prime?

Comment: I'd say $10^n - 1 = 99\dots99$. So $p$ divides $a_n$ but doesn't divide $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_n$? This feels contradictory.

Comment: Sorry, typo. It's corrected

Comment: I think you mean $\dfrac{10^{n}-1}9$

Comment: Yes sir. That's what I mean, thanks

Comment: $a_n$ still remains?

Comment: The answer is yes (but I don't recall the details of how to work it out). This has to do with the theory of cyclotomic polynomials, that $a^n-b^n$ always has a prime that doesn't divide a smaller value of $n$, except in a unique case of $(a,b)$, which is not $(10,1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, every repunit has a characteristic prime. This follows from [Bang-Zsigmondy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem).

Comment: Yes, this is the theorem that I wanted to reference in my comment. I worked through a proof of it, but there isn't any simple direct way that I know of.

Comment: There is a proof [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-07/S0002-9939-97-03981-6/S0002-9939-97-03981-6.pdf) @CalvinLin. Maybe this is the proof you had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

In base two, there is no characteristic prime for repunits of 1 and 6, and any base that is one less than a power of two has no characteristic prime for two, but otherwise there are always a prime for each repunit.

One should note that a gaussian factorisation applies.  If the baes is of the form $ab^2$, and $c$ is odd, then the repunit for $ac$ when $a$ mocd 4=1, and $2ac$ otherwise, gives at least two primes.  The exception is or base 2, and 4 and 12.

One can write $a^n-1$ as a product of $A_m$, where $m|n$.  From this, one can show that if $p|A_m$, and $p|A_x$, then $x=mp^a$ for some integer $a$.  This means that every $A_m$ is co-prime to other values of this series, except as by the previous statement.  Most of the time $A_m$ is large enough to contain real primes.  The examples above are where $A_m$ is small enough to be $1$ or some instance of $p$ from the first sentence.

For some values of $m$, it is possible to write $A_m$ as $ (g+h\sqrt{ac}) \cdot(g-h\sqrt{ac})$.  These are also co-prime. In decimal, $m$ is an odd multiple of $20$, such as $60$ or $100$.

Note that this covers more than the rational bases.  The fibonacci numbers are covered by it.  $A_{12}$ is the product of two primes repeating from earlier places, and the factorisation happens when $m$ is an odd multiple of $10$.  In the case of $10$ itself, the split is $(6+5)(6-5)$.